# Green Husqvarna fuel can spout sticking

Tags: tools

Husqvarna fuel cans come (came?) with a green spout to make filling up fuel easier.
Unfortunately, it sometimes starts sticking and fuel is spilled everywhere: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jrZe8fNvclc .
This has happened with this can before, and the problem comes and goes on its own.

There are some discussions about grey spouts having similar issues, but those seem to be more recent ones (for example, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FgCGxL5PKTk ).

Is there a way to easily improve the green spout, so that this problem does not return?